# cakePHP 2 forms in the same view not working

Tags: forms, cakephp, model

I have a cakePHP application and I would like to have my login and signup forms to be in the same page I followed this tutorial : [http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/RabidFire/2010/06/26/multiple-forms-per-page-for-the-same-modeland](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/RabidFire/2010/06/26/multiple-forms-per-page-for-the-same-model) I was able to make the signup part working  however the login part is not working I'm getting the following error : "Missing Database Table Error: Table tblforumuserlogins for model Tbluserlogin was not found in datasource default." 
                                                                                           This is the controller I'm using :

```
    class TblusersController extends AppController {

        public function signup() {
            $this->loadModel('Tbluser');
            $this->loadModel('Tbluserlogin');

            if (!empty($this->data)) {
                if (isset($this->data['Tbluser'])) { // Check if the signup Form was submitted

                   $this->Session->setFlash("SignUp Form was submitted.","notif");

                } else if (isset($this->data['Tbluserlogin'])) { // Check if the login Form was submitted
                    $this->Session->setFlash("Login Form was submitted.","notif");
                }

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The models I'm using are :
Tbluser.php

```
 <?php

    class Tbluser extends AppModel{

        public $validate = array(
            'username'=>array(
                array(
                    'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                    'allowEmpty'=>false,
                    'message'=>'Invalide Username!'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                    'message' => 'Username has to be more than 3 chars'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule'=>'isUnique',
                    'message'=>'Username already taken!'
                )
            ),
            'password' => array(
                    array(
                        'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                        'allowEmpty'=>false,
                        'message' => 'Password must be AlphaNumeric!'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                        'message' => 'Username has to be more that 3 chars'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'rule' => array('confirmPassword', 'cakehashedpassword'),
                        'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
                    )), 
            'email'=>array(
                array(
                    'rule'=>array('email',true),
                    'required'=>true,
                    'allowEmpty'=>false,
                    'message'=>'Invalide email adress!'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule'=>'isUnique',
                    'message'=>'Mail adress already taken!'
                )
            )
        );
    }
    ?>
```

The Tbluserlogin.php model :

```
<?php 
class Tblforumuserlogin extends Tblforumuser{

}
?>
```

my view file is "signup.ctp"

```
<h4>Sign up</h4>    
<div><?php echo $this->Session->flash();?></div>
<?php                   

echo $this->Form->create("Tblforumuser", array('url' => '/Tblusers/signup')); 
echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>'Username<b style="color:red;">')); 
echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>'Password<b style="color:red;">','type' => 'password')); 
echo $this->Form->input('email' ,array('label'=>'Email<b style="color:red;">'));
echo $this->Form->end('Register');

?> 

<h4>Log in to Ohyeahhh</h4> 
<div><?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?></div>
<?php echo $this->Form->create("Tbluserlogin", array('url' => '/Tblusers/signup'));  ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>"Username :")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Login'); ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not following the CakePHP conventions, therefore CakePHP is unable to *automatically* find the right database-table to use;

By default, a CakePHP model should be named after the database-table; e.g. for table `foos` (plural), the model should be named `Foo` (singular).

If you're not following the conventions, you should manually specify which table to use for a Model via the `useTable` property;

```
class Tblforumuserlogin extends Tblforumuser
{
    public $useTable = 'tblforumusers';
}
```

Using the same property, this also allows you to create more 'friendly' model names (that is, if you're unable to rename the database-tables, which is probably a better way to do this);

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'tblforumusers';
]
```

#### Alternative approach

Since both models are only used to differentiate 'which' form has been submitted, this seems like a lot of overhead here. An alternative approach is to just use the 'normal' model, but point the action to a separate 'login' action;

```
class TblusersController extends AppController
{
    public $uses = array(
        'Tbluser';
    );

    public function signup()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
             // handle sign-up
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
             if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                 $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl);
             }
        }

        // Login failed or no form submitted
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'signup'));
    }
}
```

And inside your view;

```
echo $this->Form->create("Tblforumuser"); 
echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>'Username<b style="color:red;">')); 
echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>'Password<b style="color:red;">')); 
echo $this->Form->input('email' ,array('label'=>'Email<b style="color:red;">'));
echo $this->Form->end('Register');


echo $this->Form->create("Tblforumuser", array('action' => 'login')); 

// etc...

echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

### Still another approach

Just add a hidden field to your forms to indicate which form has been sent;

```
echo $this->Form->create("Tblforumuser"); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'register'));
// etc...
echo $this->Form->end('Register');


echo $this->Form->create("Tblforumuser"); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'login'));
// etc...
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

And inside your controller;

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ('register' === $this->request->data['Tblforumuser']['formsent']) {
        // register
    } else {
        // login
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answers. Indeed the 2 solutions can work I tested the last one and it works however because I left only one module witch is Tblforumuser now my both forms are being subject of validations when submiting one of them wich is not what I want so how do I make the validation occurs only on the form I will submit? Thanks